# How to check if checkbox is enabled in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

so I was assigned to create a Health Club Membership Fee Calculator Form
The Health Club needs an application that calculates the membership fee of their club
members. Develop a VB application that allows a user to choose the type of membership from a
group of options. The program must allow the user to enter the membership length (number of
months) and the fees (monthly fee and total fee). Also, it must allow entering the desired options
such as Yoga, Karate, and Personal Trainer.

I have written a bit of the code but I'm having problems in the part where the user selects the additional options like yoga or karate and personal trainer {if yoga is selected the MonthlyBaseFee increments by 10 if Karate is selected the MonthlyBaseFee increments by 30 and if the PersonalTrainer option is selected the MonthlyBaseFee increments by 50}

here is the code

```
Public Class Form1
Public MonthlyBaseFee As Integer
Public Yoga = 10

Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim Adult As Integer
    Dim Child As Integer
    Dim Student As Integer
    Dim Senior As Integer
    Dim MonthlyBaseFee As Integer
    Dim Months As Integer


    If Int32.TryParse(TxtMonth.Text, Months) Then
    Else MessageBox.Show("please introduce a valid number")

    End If


    If radAdult.Checked = True Then
        If chkYoga.Checked Then
            MonthlyBaseFee = +10
        End If
        MonthlyBaseFee = 40 * Months
        Adult = MonthlyBaseFee
        lblMonthlyFee.Text = Adult

    ElseIf radChild.Checked = True Then
        MonthlyBaseFee = 20 * Months
        Child = MonthlyBaseFee
        lblMonthlyFee.Text = Child

    ElseIf radStudent.Checked = True Then
        MonthlyBaseFee = 25 * Months
        Student = MonthlyBaseFee
        lblMonthlyFee.Text = Student

    ElseIf radSenior.Checked = True Then
        MonthlyBaseFee = 30 * Months
        Senior = MonthlyBaseFee
        lblMonthlyFee.Text = Senior
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `MonthlyBaseFee = +10` should be `MonthlyBaseFee += 10`. And you can do the same thing for the other two CheckBoxes.

Comment: Are we doing your homework?

Comment: SteveCinq: no you're not doing my homework, I just have doubts.

Comment: If the `TryParse()` fails and you hit that else block, you should probably call `Exit Sub` after the message so that the calculations below aren't run.  Also, what if they enter a NEGATIVE number?...that'll pass the `TryParse()` test, but won't be very useful in the context of your project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `Not` to your `.TryParse` you can skip the `Else`. I am happy to see you validating user input. Replacing the text box with a `NumericUpDown` control would save having to validate.

Use `RadioButton`s for the Adult, Child, Student, Senoir. `RadioButton`s allow only one choice. So, we can use a little bit of Linq magic to find the checked `RadioButton`. If you set the `.Text` properties of the radio buttons to Adult, Child, Student, and Senior, we can use a `Select Case` to assign the appropriate fee.

Next, just check the check boxes and adjust the fee. The `.Checked` property of a `CheckBox` returns `True` or `False` so we don't need to include the `= True`.

I put the result in a label formatted with `"C2"` which is currency with 2 decimal places.

```
Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim MonthlyBaseFee As Integer
    Dim Months As Integer


    If Not Int32.TryParse(TxtMonth.Text, Months) Then
        MessageBox.Show("please introduce a valid number")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim rButton As RadioButton = Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    If rButton Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please make a selection.")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Select Case rButton.Text
            Case "Adult"
                MonthlyBaseFee = 40
            Case "Child"
                MonthlyBaseFee = 10
            Case "Student"
                MonthlyBaseFee = 25
            Case "Senior"
                MonthlyBaseFee = 30
        End Select
    End If

    If chkYoga.Checked Then
        MonthlyBaseFee += 10
    End If
    If chkKarate.Checked Then
        MonthlyBaseFee += 30
    End If
    If chkPersonalTrainer.Checked Then
        MonthlyBaseFee += 50
    End If

    Dim Total = MonthlyBaseFee * Months
    Label1.Text = Total.ToString("C2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Aren't you're falling out out the 'MessageBox' into the rest of the code? Should you be exiting if the entered number is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have code for the many of the options you mention, but for what you have, here're some corrections/suggestions:

```
Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    'Dim Adult As Integer = 0
    'Dim Child As Integer = 0
    'Dim Student As Integer = 0
    'Dim Senior As Integer = 0
    Dim MonthlyBaseFee As Integer = 0
    Dim Months As Integer = 0

    If Int32.TryParse(txtMonth.Text, Months) Then
        Select Case True
            Case radAdult.Checked
                If chkYoga.Checked Then MonthlyBaseFee += 10 '<- This never changes MonthlyBaseFee because it is overwritten on the next line!
                MonthlyBaseFee = 40 * Months
                'Adult = MonthlyBaseFee
            Case radChild.Checked
                MonthlyBaseFee = 20 * Months
                'Child = MonthlyBaseFee
            Case radStudent.Checked
                MonthlyBaseFee = 25 * Months
                'Student = MonthlyBaseFee
            Case radSenior.Checked
                MonthlyBaseFee = 30 * Months
                'Senior = MonthlyBaseFee
        End Select
        lblMonthlyFee.Text = MonthlyBaseFee.ToString()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please introduce a valid number.")
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**: Since `Adult`, `Child`, `Student` and `Senior` are all set to `MonthlyBaseFee` and never used again, you can set `lblMonthlyBaseFee.Text` directly to `MonthlyBaseFee` outside of the `Case` block and probably dispense with the individual variables (unless they are used elsewhere in your code).

Comment: While all valid based off the sample code, by using a case aren't you assuming that each of the options are mutually  exclusive.  Getting back to the OP question, it would mean the user can only select fro example yoga or Karate.  It might be quite legitimate to to do both yoga and karate

Comment: @Hursey The Op uses `ElseIf`s, not individual `If`s and there is no final `Else`. So `Case Select` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put in group box the checkbox that you want only one to be checked, for example to group adult, children, senior,student.

if can select 1 or multiple of option of Yoga you can leave it separate in your form

the multiplication is add the end I think you want to show in a label  lblTotalFees.Text

```
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim Adult As Integer
        Dim Child As Integer
        Dim Student As Integer
        Dim Senior As Integer
        Dim MonthlyBaseFee As Integer
        Dim Months As Integer

        Dim TotalFees As Integer

        If Int32.TryParse(TxtMonth.Text, Months) Then
        Else MessageBox.Show("please introduce a valid number")

        End If


        If radAdult.Checked = True Then
            MonthlyBaseFee = 40
            Adult = MonthlyBaseFee
        End If

        If radChild.Checked = True Then
            MonthlyBaseFee = 20
            Child = MonthlyBaseFee
        End If

        If radStudent.Checked = True Then
            MonthlyBaseFee = 25
            Student = MonthlyBaseFee
        End If

        If radSenior.Checked = True Then
            MonthlyBaseFee = 30
            Senior = MonthlyBaseFee
        End If



        If chkYoga.Checked Then
            MonthlyBaseFee += 10
            lblMonthlyFee.Text = MonthlyBaseFee.ToString
        End If

        If chkKarate.Checked Then
            MonthlyBaseFee += 30
            lblMonthlyFee.Text = MonthlyBaseFee.ToString
        End If

        If chkPersonalTrainer.Checked Then
            MonthlyBaseFee += 50
            lblMonthlyFee.Text = MonthlyBaseFee.ToString
        End If


        TotalFees = Months * MonthlyBaseFee
        lblTotalFees.Text = TotalFees.ToString


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Op is using `ElseIf`s, not individual `If`s.